# How to load images via file open dialog in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, openfiledialog, testcafe, web-testing

**Background info:**

Our application depends on different sets of medical images (due to the medical environment we can't share our code). In each image, a set of test cases is run. Each time we need to manually select a new image, which of course we want to automate. The loading of images is fairly complex, but our devs created a button that covers all that. This **button** opens a **File open dialog**.

**My Question:**

How can I open a file dialog window and import new images with TestCafe?

**We've tried:**

- t.setFilesToUpload (which not seems to work because it needs a selector where the images get uploaded to?)
- List item clicking the button (it does not open the dialog
  window)

Comment: `t.setFilesToUpload` should work. Could you please share some detailed information about how that button works? It should upload images at a certain place as well.